# jQuery tab losing CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider:

```
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Tab1">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tab2">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tab3">C</a></li>
    </ul><br />

    <div id="Tab1" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#InnerTab1">Inner A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#InnerTab1">Inner B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#InnerTab1">Inner C</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="InnerTab1">Welcome to Inner Tab1</div>
        <div id="InnerTab2"><p>Welcome to Inner Tab1</p></div>
        <div id="InnerTab3"><p>Welcome to Inner Tab1</p></div>
   </div>
   <div id="Tab2"><p>Tab2</p></div>
   <div id="Tab3"><p>Tab3</p></div>
</div>
```

The above code is in a PartialView named ABC.

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Action", new { Id = item.CustomerID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Abc" })%>
```

And the above code is in a partial view as well named XYZ.

So I have two partial views, Abc and XYZ. These two partial views are called on one view. On the view XYZ, I have a actionLink button on the click of which I am able to fill in details in ABC.

Now, in ABC I have a Tab panel as shown in the above code. When the page is load for the first time, I get the jQuery tab properly displayed. When I click on the ActionLink button, the tabs are displayed in the form of List.

I don't know what is happeneing. So this is my problem. Why are they losing their CSS on the click of action link?

I have included all the jQuery files in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) Tabs component is not just CSS - it also uses JavaScript code to modify the elements under #tabs. When you click on the link, everything inside ABC is replaced with the version from the server, which does not include those modifications.

If you are using unobtrusive Ajax updates on an element that contains tabs, you will need to add an OnComplete handler to AjaxOptions that calls `$("#tabs").tabs()` to redo those modifications after the HTML is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom Can u give me an example how to do it

Comment: `new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Abc", OnComplete="function(){$('#tabs').tabs();}" }` should do it.

Comment: Tom I tried this code but It didnt work
as I told u that link button is on a partialview and the tabs are on another partial view....
and there is a tab inside a tab

Comment: Well, something similar should work - The partial view is irrelevant in this context, and I can't do all your debugging for you. One further hint though - having more than one element with the id "tabs" can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: Tom I have tried debugging from my end using mozilla 
When I check the css file on mozilla on 1st time for the tabs then I can see the css code being called
but when I click on the link tabs losses the css, ie the css is not called, I guess this is the problem existing

Comment: no, the problem is exactly what I have told you - when you recreate the html with Ajax.ActionLink you also need to make the call to tabs again, the same as you have in yuor page load script.